# Creating 3D Convolutional Layer

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

ValueError: One of the dimensions in the output is <= 0 due to downsampling in conv3d_15. Consider increasing the input size. Received input shape [None, 1, 1, 1, 1904211] which would produce output shape with a zero or negative value in a dimension.

Can anyone explain me what is the meaning of this error

While i am trying to build my 3d convolutional neural network. I got this erro

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A 3D convolution layer expect the input to be in a shape similar to (4, 28, 28, 28, 1). For 28x28x28 volumes with a single channel. More info here - https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv3D